# Trying to return a single row of data using a class method. Only the value of the primary key is returned

Tags: php

I'm working on a Mac Catalina with MAMP PHP 8.

For one of my study assessments, I'm building an online store based on PHP HTML and CSS using a small database. I'm in the process of PHP coding and have everything working except displaying the data of a single product item. I have a class Item.php and a method `getItem($itemId)`.

If I `print_r()` hard coding the `$itemId` I get all data as below.

```
<?php
        require_once "classes/Item.php";

        $item = new Item();

        // print_r($item);

        $item->getItem(7);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($item);
        echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

```
Item Object
(
    [_itemId:Item:private] => 7
    [_itemName:Item:private] => Adidas must have stripes tee
    [_photo:Item:private] => blackTop.jpg
    [_price:Item:private] => 34.99
    [_salePrice:Item:private] => 
    [_description:Item:private] => Built for busy training schedules, the adidas Boys Aeroready 3-Stripes Tee is a must have for budding young athletes.
    [_featured:Item:private] => 0
    [_itemCategoryName:Item:private] => 
    [_db:Item:private] => DBAccess Object
        (
            [_DSN:DBAccess:private] => mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sportswh;charset=utf8
            [_username:DBAccess:private] => root
            [_password:DBAccess:private] => root
            [_pdo:DBAccess:private] => PDO Object
                (
                )

        )

    [_categoryId] => 4
)
```

However, building it out to display on a page only returns the primary key value as per the code following. Note there are several echos that I was using to try and debug.

***THE METHOD***

```
<?php
// 2. A method to get and return values for a single item using the itemId i.e. the primary key.
    public function getItem($itemId) {
        // Begin try/catch. 
        try {
            // Connect to the database.
            $pdo = $this->_db->connect();
            // Assign an SQL statement calling for all information about a single item to variable $sql. Use a placeholder for itemId.
            $sql = "SELECT * 
                    FROM item
                    WHERE itemId = :itemId";
            // Prepare the statement. 
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            // Bind the placeholder to the value. 
            $stmt->bindValue(':itemId', $itemId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            // Execute the SQL statement and assign to $rows. 
            $itemRows = $this->_db->executeSQL($stmt);
            // Get the row (there will only be one row).
            $itemRow = $itemRows[0];
            // Assign the values to the properties.
            $this->_itemId = $itemRow["itemId"];
            $this->_itemName = $itemRow["itemName"];
            $this->_price = $itemRow["price"];
            $this->_salePrice = $itemRow["salePrice"];
            $this->_description = $itemRow["description"];
            $this->_featured = $itemRow["featured"];
            $this->_categoryId = $itemRow["categoryId"];
            $this->_photo = $itemRow["photo"];
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
?>
```

***PHP***

```
<?php
    // Call the Item class.
    require_once "classes/Item.php";

    // Insert page title and heading. 
    $title = "Sports Warehouse - Display Product";
    $pageHeading = "Sports Warehouse - Product Information";

    // Create a new DBAccess object using the constructor method.
    $singleItem = new Item();

    // $row = "";

    if(isset($_GET["ID"])) {
        $itemId = $_GET["ID"];
        echo $itemId; // displays
        // Retrieve the single row using the getItem method of the Item class. 
        $itemRow = $singleItem->getItem($itemId);

        echo "beetroot"; // displays
        echo $itemId; // displays

        // Start the buffer. 
        ob_start();

        // Insert the product information display.
        include "templates/product-item.html.php";

    }
    else {
        echo "The if statement didn't work mate.";
    }

    // Empty the buffer the $output variable. 
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    // Add the HTML layout. 
    include "templates/layout.html.php";
?>
```

***HTML***

```
<table>
    <?php
        $itemName = $itemRow["itemName"];
        $price = $itemRow["price"];
        $salePrice = $itemRow["salePrice"];
        $description = $itemRow["description"];
        $categoryName = $itemRow["categoryName"];
        $photo = $itemRow["photo"];
        echo $itemId; // displays
        echo $description; // does NOT display
    ?>
</table>
    <article class="product1">
        <div class="product-image">
        <img src="images/products/176-<?= $photo ?>" alt="<?= $itemName ?>">
        </div>
        <!--  Start: Product Pricing -->
        <div class="product-price">
            <p class="product-price__pricing"><span class="product-price__price">$<?= $price ?></span></p>
        </div>
        <!--  End: Product Pricing -->
        <!--  Start: On Sale Pricing -->
        <div class="on-sale">
            <p class="on-sale__pricing" ><span class="on-sale__price">$<?= $salePrice ?></span></p>
            <p class="on-sale__markdown"><span class="on-sale__was upper-case">was</span> <span class="on-sale__markdown-price">$<?= $price ?></span></p>
        </div>
        <!--  End: On Sale Pricing -->
        <h3 class="product-title"><?= $itemName ?></h3>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <p><?= $description ?></p>
    </article>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you try to access $itemRow as an array, but this is object: $itemRow["itemName"] should be $itemRow->_itemName. There might be also a problem with accessing variables, as they are private.

Comment: Hi, Just confirming how I got it working: I require a "return $itemRow" statement as the last line in the try/catch. Thanks Steve L

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming how I got it working: I require a "return $itemRow" statement as the last line in the try/catch. Thanks Steve L

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30380664)